# Linux API to determine sockets owned by a process

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

Is there a Linux library that will enable me to tell what IP sockets are owned by what processes? I guess I'm looking for the programmatic equivalent of `lsof -i`. Ultimately, I want to correlate packets seen through `libpcap` to processes.

**UPDATE:** A couple of people have suggested using `/proc/<pid>/net/tcp` and `udp`, but on my system, the same data is shown for every process, so it doesn't help.

Comment: oh wow. i'm writing a program to do just this right now, what a coincidence

Comment: I have code now if you're interested in comparing notes. I've seen a couple rare quirks in the /proc data, but overall the approach works.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think you first have to look through the open fds in /proc/*/fd, e.g.

```
4 -> socket:[11147]
```

and then look for the referenced sockets (by the inode) in /proc/net/tcp (or /proc/net/udp), e.g.

```
12: B382595D:8B40 D5C43B45:0050 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 11065 1 ffff88008bd35480 69 4 12 4 -1
```

Comment: This is the missing link. Thanks! (Won't let me upvote for some reason.)

Comment: You answered this while I was writing, and I didn't notice... good job :)  +1 since OP apparently can't.

Comment: This answer could be even better if the inodes in the 2 examples matched each other.

Comment: Look at /proc/XXX/net/tcp, it only contains sockets opened by the process whose pid is XXX.

Comment: fossilet, /proc/<pid>/net/tcp contains all (tcp) sockets in the network namespace of the process, not just the ones opened by the process.

Answer (score 14):

To determine sockets owned by a process you can just use `netstat`. Here's an example w/output (shortened) of `netstat` with options that will do what you want.

```
$ sudo netstat -apeen
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8118          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      138        744850      13248/privoxy   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      117        9612        2019/postgres   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51960         127.0.0.1:51960         ESTABLISHED 117        7957        2019/postgres   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          7740        1989/dhclient   
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7937     2019/postgres       /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     958058   8080/emacs          /tmp/emacs1000/server
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6969     1625/Xorg           /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9325     1989/dhclient       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7720     1625/Xorg           @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

Make sure you run netstat as root otherwise you'll get this message:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

An explanation of the `-apeen` options from the [netstat manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?netstat+8):

```
-a, --all
    Show both listening and non-listening sockets. With the
    --interfaces option, show interfaces that are not up

-p, --program
    Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket
    belongs.

-e, --extend
    Display additional information. Use this option twice for
    maximum detail.

--numeric , -n
    Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names.

--numeric-hosts
    shows numerical host addresses but does not affect the resolution of port or user names.

--numeric-ports
    shows numerical port numbers but does not affect the resolution of host or user names.

--numeric-users
    shows numerical user IDs but does not affect the resolution of host or port names.
```

Comment: you can get the pid if you sudo to the owner of that process (if you can't get root).  +1 on this solution!  Thanks!

Comment: `netstat` will actually parse `/proc/net/tcp` et al. see, for example, [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/code/ci/master/tree/netstat.c#l979) (parse code for `/proc/net/tcp`). Paths in use by netstat defined in `lib/pathnames.h`.

Answer (score 11):

The `/proc` filesystem provides details on each process, including networking information.  Open socket information is listed in `/proc/net/tcp`.  The IPv6 sockets are listed separately in the `tcp6` file.  The socket information includes information such as the local and remote ports, and the socket inode number, which can be mapped back to the process by parsing the `/proc/{pid}/fd/*` information.

If you aren't familiar with the `/proc` filesystem, it is basically a virtual filesystem that allows the kernel to publish all sorts of useful information to user-space.  The files are normally simple structured text files that are easy to parse.

For example, on my Ubuntu system I used `netcat` for testing, and ran `nc -l -p 8321` to listen on port 8321.  Looking at the `tcp` socket information:

```
$ cat /proc/net/tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 00000000:2081 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 26442 1 de0c8e40 300 0 0 2 -1                             
   1: 0100007F:0277 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 7019 1 de0c84c0 300 0 0 2 -1
```

The first line shows it is listening on all addresses to point 8321 (0x2081).  The inode number is 26442, which we can use to look up the matching pid in `/proc/{pid}/fd/*`, which consists of a bunch of symlinks from the file handle number to the device.  So if we look up the pid for `netcat`, and check its `fd` mapping:

```
$ ls -l /proc/7266/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 gavinb gavinb 64 2009-12-31 09:10 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 gavinb gavinb 64 2009-12-31 09:10 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 gavinb gavinb 64 2009-12-31 09:10 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 gavinb gavinb 64 2009-12-31 09:10 3 -> socket:[26442]
```

And there we see that file descriptor 3 in this process is mapped to the socket with inode 26442, just as we expect.

So obviously to build a complete map of sockets, you will need to first enumerate all the `/proc/**/fd/*` files, look up the socket symlinks, then match the socket inode against the tables from `/proc/net/tcp` which has the endpoint information.

This is the way the `lsof` tool works (see `lsof/dialects/linux/dsocket.c` for the implementation).

- [Wikipedia on procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)
- [The Linux /proc filesystem as a Programmer's Tool](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8381)

Comment: Same question as I had for Kimvais: The /proc/*/net/tcp directories show the same data for different pids. How can I map each one back to the source pid?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include a full description of how to map sockets to pids.  I hope this is clearer now - it basically involves building a table of pids to socket inodes, and looking up these inodes in the tcp socket table. Let me know if there's anything that needs clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

`/proc/<pid>/net` is equivalent to `/proc/net` for all processes in the same network namespace as you – in other words, it's "global" information.

You can do what `lsof` and `fuser` do, which is to iterate through both `/proc/<pid>/fd/*` and `/proc/net/*` looking for matching inodes.  Quick demonstration:

```
#!/bin/sh
pgrep "$@" | while read pid; do
    for fd in /proc/$pid/fd/*; do
        name=$(readlink $fd)
        case $name in
            socket:\[*\])
                ino=${name#*:}
                for proto in tcp:10 tcp6:10 udp:10 udp6:10 unix:7; do
                    [[ ! -e /proc/net/${proto%:*} ]] ||
                    awk "
                        \$${proto##*:} == ${ino:1:${#ino}-2} {
                            print \"${proto%:*}:\", \$0
                            exit 1
                        }
                    " /proc/net/${proto%:*} || break
                done
                ;;
        esac
    done
done
```

You can extend this to other protocols (I see ax25, ipx, packet, raw, raw6, udplite, udp6lite in `/proc/net/` too) or rewrite in a language of your choosing.

Answer (score 4):

You can read them from proc filesystem. The 'files' you probably want to look at are found in
`/proc/<pid>/net` (namely tcp, udp, unix)

Here's some [examples](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8381) on using the proc filesystem

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but /proc/*/net/tcp shows the same data for different pids. Must be showing all connections. How can I map each one back to the source pid?

Answer (score 3):

You could try running lsof with strace and see just which files in /proc it gets data from.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go to the source:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1346778