# Does /proc/[pid]/net/tcp refers to only to sockets owned by [pid]?

Tags: linux

Does /proc/[pid]/net/tcp refers to only to sockets owned by [pid]?

If yes, looping through /proc numeric-only directories (ie. pids) and reading /proc/[pid]/net/tcp would be a safe/correct way to list each socket owned by each pid? ie. kinda like the functionality netstat -p provides, but I would like to do it in C and I wouldn't like to parse netstat output.

As an addendum, is there a reference for the connection status column? What each byte means? Or reading the kernel source would be the only way to find out?

Is the "format" of each proc entry be stable along Linux kernel versions?

Comment: To answer the first part of your question, yes, looping over `/proc` is a good way to see what sockets each program has open. You can also check `/proc/<pid>/fd/` to see all of its open file descriptors, which will includes sockets of all types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980355/linux-api-to-determine-sockets-owned-by-a-process